# Update widget by pressing a button

Tags: android, widget, refresh, android-pendingintent, android-12

I'm trying to make a widget refresh button. I found this code, it works great on android 11. But on version 12 and higher, it breaks the application. What could be the problem?

```
// onReceive function to process clicks
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)

        if (intent.action == AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE) {
            val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
            val appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS)

            if (appWidgetIds != null) {
                for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
                    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
                }
            }
        }
}

// add PendingIntent
val updateWidgetIntent = Intent(context, NextLectureWidget::class.java)
updateWidgetIntent.action = AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE
updateWidgetIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, intArrayOf(appWidgetId))
val updateWidgetPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context, 0, updateWidgetIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.updateButton, updateWidgetPendingIntent)
```